# How can I know which component View & Text belong to when app throws exception `Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not supported on Android`

Tags: react-native

Here is my two following components. `MovieItem` is used in `MovieList`. And the app throws the exception.

My question is in a complex application, there are so many components were defined, are there any fast way to indentify which components that `View` & `Text` belong to when we look into error message? Many thanks.

**Exception**

```
ExceptionsManager.js:63 Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not supported on Android.
handleException @   ExceptionsManager.js:63
handleError @   InitializeCore.js:114
reportFatalError    @   error-guard.js:44
guard   @   MessageQueue.js:48
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   MessageQueue.js:107
(anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:71
```

**movie-list.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MovieItem from './movie-item';
import {
  Text
} from 'react-native';

class MovieList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        This is movie list
        <MovieItem />
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieList;
```

**movie-item.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View, Text
} from 'react-native';
import Image from 'react-native-image-progress';
import Progress from 'react-native-progress';

class MovieItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image 
          indicator={Progress}
          source={{uri: "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

As exception message states you need to move MovieItem from Text body. You can move it to new View which will contain both Text and MovieItem elements, like this:

```
<View>  
  <Text>
    This is movie list
  </Text>
  <MovieItem/>
</View>
```

Comment: Yeah, already fixed with your suggestion :) btw, do you know how can we indicate the `<View>` & `<Text>` location when we look into error message?

Answer (score 0):

like this：

```js
<Text
allowFontScaling={false}
ref="titleText" numberOfLines={2}
style={styles.titleTextStyle}>
{item.contentType ? <Image
source={item.contentType === '0' ?
require('../../../../foundation/Img/searchpage/Icon_globalbuy_tag_.png') :
item.contentType === '1' ?                         require('../../../../foundation/Img/searchpage/Icon_anchorrecommend_tag_.png') :                                         item.contentType === '3' ?               require('../../../../foundation/Img/searchpage/Icon_groupbuy_tag2_.png')                                                     require('../../../../foundation/Img/searchpage/tag_shangcheng.png') }                                        
style={styles.iconStyle}/> : null}
{item.title}</Text>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can change the layout:

```
<View>
<Text />
<OtherWidget/>
...
</View>
```